# Spark S3 Committers not writing anything

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

My Spark cluster has the following setup:

```
Hadoop 3.1
Spark 2.4.4
Scala 2.12.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_212)

JARs:
hadoop-aws-3.1.0.jar
spark-hadoop-cloud_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.0.6-1.jar
```

These are the relevant Spark settings:

```
(spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.staging.unique-filenames,true)
(spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl,org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem)
(spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.name,partitioned)
(spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version,10)
(spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.staging.abort.pending.uploads,true)
(spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm,SSE-KMS)
(spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class,org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.BindingParquetOutputCommitter)
(spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.magic.enabled,false)
(spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.staging.conflict-mode,replace)
(spark.sql.sources.commitProtocolClass,org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.PathOutputCommitProtocol)
(spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl,org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem)
```

There are no S3 permissions error, having followed this link:
https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/bk_cloud-data-access/content/iam-role-permissions.html

```
s3:Get*
s3:Delete*
s3:Put*
s3:ListBucket
s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads
s3:AbortMultipartUpload
```

This is the output of my `_SUCCESS` file:

```
{
  "name" : "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.commit.files.SuccessData/1",
  "timestamp" : 1586969903889,
  "date" : "Thu Apr 16 00:58:23 SGT 2020",
  "hostname" : "<removed>",
  "committer" : "partitioned",
  "description" : "Task committer attempt_20200416005750_0000_m_000000_0",
  "metrics" : {
    "stream_write_block_uploads" : 0,
    "files_created" : 0,
    "S3guard_metadatastore_put_path_latencyNumOps" : 0,
    "stream_write_block_uploads_aborted" : 0,
    "committer_commits_reverted" : 0,
    "op_open" : 0,
    "stream_closed" : 0,
    "committer_magic_files_created" : 0,
    "object_copy_requests" : 0,
    "s3guard_metadatastore_initialization" : 0,
    "S3guard_metadatastore_put_path_latency90thPercentileLatency" : 0,
    "stream_write_block_uploads_committed" : 0,
    "S3guard_metadatastore_throttle_rate75thPercentileFrequency (Hz)" : 0,
    "S3guard_metadatastore_throttle_rate90thPercentileFrequency (Hz)" : 0,
    "committer_bytes_committed" : 0,
    "op_create" : 0,
    "stream_read_fully_operations" : 0,
    "committer_commits_completed" : 0,
    "object_put_requests_active" : 0,
    "s3guard_metadatastore_retry" : 0,
    "stream_write_block_uploads_active" : 0,
    "stream_opened" : 0,
    "S3guard_metadatastore_throttle_rate95thPercentileFrequency (Hz)" : 0,
    "op_create_non_recursive" : 0,
    "object_continue_list_requests" : 0,
    "committer_jobs_completed" : 1,
    "S3guard_metadatastore_put_path_latency50thPercentileLatency" : 0,
    "stream_close_operations" : 0,
    "stream_read_operations" : 0,
    "object_delete_requests" : 0,
    "fake_directories_deleted" : 0,
    "stream_aborted" : 0,
    "op_rename" : 0,
    "object_multipart_aborted" : 0,
    "committer_commits_created" : 0,
    "op_get_file_status" : 5,
    "s3guard_metadatastore_put_path_request" : 3,
    "committer_commits_failed" : 0,
    "stream_bytes_read_in_close" : 0,
    "op_glob_status" : 0,
    "stream_read_exceptions" : 0,
    "op_exists" : 3,
    "S3guard_metadatastore_throttle_rate50thPercentileFrequency (Hz)" : 0,
    "S3guard_metadatastore_put_path_latency95thPercentileLatency" : 0,
    "stream_write_block_uploads_pending" : 0,
    "directories_created" : 0,
    "S3guard_metadatastore_throttle_rateNumEvents" : 0,
    "S3guard_metadatastore_put_path_latency99thPercentileLatency" : 0,
    "stream_bytes_backwards_on_seek" : 0,
    "stream_bytes_read" : 0,
    "stream_write_total_data" : 0,
    "committer_jobs_failed" : 0,
    "stream_read_operations_incomplete" : 0,
    "files_copied_bytes" : 0,
    "op_delete" : 0,
    "object_put_bytes_pending" : 0,
    "stream_write_block_uploads_data_pending" : 0,
    "op_list_located_status" : 0,
    "object_list_requests" : 6,
    "stream_forward_seek_operations" : 0,
    "committer_tasks_completed" : 0,
    "committer_commits_aborted" : 0,
    "object_metadata_requests" : 10,
    "object_put_requests_completed" : 0,
    "stream_seek_operations" : 0,
    "op_list_status" : 1,
    "store_io_throttled" : 0,
    "stream_write_failures" : 0,
    "op_get_file_checksum" : 0,
    "files_copied" : 0,
    "ignored_errors" : 0,
    "committer_bytes_uploaded" : 0,
    "committer_tasks_failed" : 0,
    "stream_bytes_skipped_on_seek" : 0,
    "op_list_files" : 0,
    "files_deleted" : 0,
    "stream_bytes_discarded_in_abort" : 0,
    "op_mkdirs" : 0,
    "op_copy_from_local_file" : 0,
    "op_is_directory" : 1,
    "s3guard_metadatastore_throttled" : 0,
    "S3guard_metadatastore_put_path_latency75thPercentileLatency" : 0,
    "stream_write_total_time" : 0,
    "stream_backward_seek_operations" : 0,
    "object_put_requests" : 0,
    "object_put_bytes" : 0,
    "directories_deleted" : 0,
    "op_is_file" : 0,
    "S3guard_metadatastore_throttle_rate99thPercentileFrequency (Hz)" : 0
  },
  "diagnostics" : {
    "fs.s3a.metadatastore.impl" : "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.s3guard.NullMetadataStore",
    "fs.s3a.committer.magic.enabled" : "false",
    "fs.s3a.metadatastore.authoritative" : "false"
  },
  "filenames" : [ ]
}
```

To test a write, i simply do the following:

```
scala> val df = spark.read.parquet(<origin>) // have confirmed that the df is not empty
scala> df.write.format("parquet").save(<destination>) // have confirmed when FileCommitter is used, output is written
```

Possible problems:

1) My Spark cluster is hosted on Nomad, with no HDFS set up. I've confirmed that the data is being written locally to disk on the Spark workers in a `/tmp/staging` directory, but not being written to s3.

2) ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the issue is that the staging committers require a consistent filesystem directory to stage data. Since i didn't configure the setting for this in  `fs.s3a.committer.staging.tmp.path`, my Spark cluster with no HDFS set-up were writing in their local file directory. Fixed this by configuring the setting to write to a S3 directory (with a caveat that this requires a *consistent* filesystem directory, which means S3Guard should be enabled)

https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/bk_cloud-data-access/content/ch03s08s03.html